# Create styler using google maps api 3 and js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I want to create my own stylers on my map. For example, suppose that I want to put some flowers (or something else) in the country's limits, how can I do it?

I use the google maps's stylers but there is a limit: we may use the different stylers (opacity, color ...) provided by google. How can I create my own styler?

My map use stylers like stylers you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#creating_a_styledmaptype) on google developer web site.
The documentation does not describe my problem and I tried to find some other ways in some web sites like stack overflow without success.

I will use in example the map of the documentation in order to simplified the example. So, this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Styled Map Types</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {

        // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it an array of styles,
        // and the name to be displayed on the map type control.
        var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
            [
              {elementType: 'geometry', stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]},
              {elementType: 'labels.text.fill', stylers: [{color: '#523735'}]},
              {elementType: 'labels.text.stroke', stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]},
              {
                featureType: 'administrative',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#c9b2a6'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#dcd2be'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#ae9e90'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'landscape.natural',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'poi',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#93817c'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'poi.park',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#a5b076'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'poi.park',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#447530'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'road',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#f5f1e6'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'road.arterial',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#fdfcf8'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#f8c967'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'road.highway',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#e9bc62'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#e98d58'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'road.highway.controlled_access',
                elementType: 'geometry.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#db8555'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'road.local',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#806b63'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#8f7d77'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'transit.line',
                elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                stylers: [{color: '#ebe3cd'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'transit.station',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [{color: '#dfd2ae'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#b9d3c2'}]
              },
              {
                featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'labels.text.fill',
                stylers: [{color: '#92998d'}]
              }
            ],
            {name: 'Styled Map'});

        // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
        // to the map type control.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 55.647, lng: 37.581},
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['roadmap', 'satellite', 'hybrid', 'terrain',
                    'styled_map']
          }
        });

        //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
        map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
        map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to documentation, you can only change the colors (and some definitions like saturation, lightness, etc. - as you said). If you want to put some images (like flowers onto borders), you need to create your own overlay image (a transparent image (or multiple) contains flowers as border): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple

Answer (score 2):

You could try working on custom layers.

Source:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/get-creative-and-make-your-own-maps-with-custom-layers-on-the-new-google-maps/

Comment: Your answer do not resolve totally my question but is better answer as I can see in this page. Thank you for your work.

Answer (score 1):

have you done reading/using the google custom markers?. If not [visit google custom marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) this might answer your question, who knows.

Comment: I read so much the documentation! My question is how to create some stylers and the documentation do not treat about this. You do not very well understand my question. Sorry.